# Is it possible to link directly to "rate and review"?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Can i set the link of "rate and review" page of my app ?
 Actually i want to give this link in **"About"** page of my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`MarketplaceReviewTask` Launcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394030%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) instead of a link:

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

(...)

MarketplaceReviewTask marketplaceReviewTask = new MarketplaceReviewTask();
marketplaceReviewTask.Show();
```

It's gonna open `Marketplace` app on your application page where user will be able to review your app.

Comment: thanks but i want to set it on button click "rate and review"